# How to replace image src after page load in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can change a specific part of an image src using jQuery after the page is being loaded?

This is an example link,

`<img src="https://example.com/73832d3c5fca_175x175_c0b~bn1v1.jpg">`

I want to replace the `b1n1v1` with `bn1v1` after the page is being fully rendered.

This is what I have tried to do so far but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace("b1n1v1", "bn1v1");
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why the `return`? And why you think `this` in the `ready` handler is an/the image? And why `.text()`? -> [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax isn't quite right as `this` refers to the `window` and `return` is redundant at that point.

To make this work for all `img` elements in the page you need to loop through them. To do that you can provide a function to `attr()` which accepts the current value as an argument and returns the new value. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').attr('src', function(i, s) {
    return s.replace("b1n1v1", "bn1v1");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Loop each images and replace the same `.attr('src')`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('img').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace("b1n1v1", "bn1v1"));
    });
});
```

**each** https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: What's "Bucle"?

Comment: Oh Sorry, bucle=loop=each

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a class to that image `imageClass`.

   `$('.imageClass').attr('src').replace('bn1nv1', 'bn1v1');`

Comment: This won't change any of the `src` values, and if it did it would replace the `src` of all `.imageClass` elements with the value of the first one.